# Sphinx & reStructuredText : how to link an image to a document page

Tags: image, hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In the RST syntax, you can specify a `:target:` attribute for setting a link. I would like to link the image to a "materials.rst" doc page, whose main section title is "Materials"

But neither of these work as target value:

- `` :target: `materials`_ ``
- `:target: :doc: materials`
- `:target: materials`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it - I believe it's not possible. (Similarly, I can't see a way to link to a :ref:.)

Comment: `:target: materials.html` works if you're only building html docs.

Answer (score 2):

Not fixed even after 6 years, although `:ref:` works now across files just fine. However, you can't use `:ref:` within image or figure directives.

try using this:

```
:target: materials.html
```

...and hope for the best! The `:target:` role seems to accept HTML links only.

Let's assume there is some file named doc.rst which I want to access via the thumbnail in another document:

```
.. _doc:

Some Title
==========
```

...and then, in another document, I use the following solutions:

```
.. image:: /media/thumbnail_of_my_doc.jpg
   :ref:`doc` <- doesn't compute
   :target: doc (or doc.rst, or doc_) <- doesn't work either
   :target: doc.html <- works im my case
```

The last option works just because I assumed the name of the HTML to be generated. What if I was wrong? This is a pure hack.
I can't believe no one got bothered to fix this.

I use RTD theme on Sphinx 4.2.0. all is updated to the newest versions.

Comment: It means: "don't try to be a smartass writing answers at 4 am :). Thanks for noticing, it's fixed.

Comment: I am using Sphinx 4.4.0 and it still seems to only work with :target: doc.html - or are there now any other solutions?